# The bookmark example of Spring can't be started

Tags: spring

I'm trying to run the example 'bookmark' on Spring website             http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/
Now it already has been compiled successfully by maven, but when run 'mvn spring-boot:run', it gave the error：

```
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-                                              
   maven-plugin:1.1.8.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project bookmarks: Unable
   to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property -> [Help       
   1]
```

I checked the Application.java in tut-bookmarks\rest\src\main\java\bookmarks and there's several annotations:

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan 
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

before the class contains

```
CommandLineRunner init(AccountRepository accountRepository,BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository)
```

I also checked the other examples and '@SpringBootApplication' are used. So could anybody explain the difference and help me to run the bookmark example?
Thanks.

Comment: Post the POM. You're probably missing the indicated property.

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>

 <groupId>bookmarks</groupId>
 <artifactId>bookmarks</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>

 <modules>
  <module>rest</module>
  <module>security</module>
  <module>model</module>
  <module>hateoas</module>
 </modules>

Comment: <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

Comment: sorry ,i dont know how to format XML